# Android copy local app database file to Internal device memory folder

Tags: android, backup

I want to achieve that after I click the BACKUP button, the mydb.db file from my app database folder will be copied to device internal memory, where a New folder should be created and the file put inside it.

My code what I tried:

```
   backupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        try {
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            File extdata = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            String backupDBPath = "/Newfolder/mydb.db";
            File ddir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Newfolder/");
            DirectoryExist(ddir);

            String currentDBPath ="/data/mypackage/databases/mydb.db";

            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(extdata, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is successful ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

});

private void DirectoryExist(File destination) {

    if (!destination.isDirectory()) {
        if (destination.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("Carpeta creada", "....");
        } else {
            Log.d("Carpeta no creada", "....");
        }
    }
}
```

However I have this error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Newfolder/mydb.db (No such file or directory)`

**UPDATE: After investigation I found out, it is a storage permission issue.**

If I set permissions manually in app settings, it is working. But when I try to set permissions in the app, it still says, permission denied:

```
 if(!checkPermissionForReadExtertalStorage())
            {
                try {
                    requestPermissionForReadExtertalStorage();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

public boolean checkPermissionForReadExtertalStorage() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int result = this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    return false;
}

public void requestPermissionForReadExtertalStorage() throws Exception {
    try {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The popup with permissions comes up, but still, seems it doesn't allows permissions.

In manifest I have:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not used anymore for android 10+, so not sure if I need to keep it there.
And I have also  `<application  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

But as I read: Starting in Android 11, apps that use the scoped storage model can access only their own app-specific cache files.

So it seems, there is no option to create any folder in local storage to backup files anymore except the app folder. One option seems to be via MediaStore API, but using this for backup one small db file seems to be an overkill.

Comment: On an Android 10 device?

Comment: `void DirectoryExist()` You should make that return a boolean like `boolean DirectoryExist()` and the caller should check the return value and stop if it is false. Display a toast then.

Comment: `if (!destination.isDirectory())` You should use File:exists() instead.

Comment: on all devices >23, not only Android 10. DirectoryExist only checks if the directory exists, if not, then creaes it. But the problem is here File backupDB = new File(extdata, backupDBPath); As the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); gives me a path under emulated/0/ and not sdcard0

Comment: That is irrelevant as they point to the same storage location. Please change DirectoryExist as proposed, update your code, post the new error message, then we can continue.

Comment: ok, now I found out what is the problem. The permissions! However in manifest I have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but it doesn't provides access from Android 10+ anymore, so not sure if to keep it. I also have application  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true", but it did not help. I went to app settings on device and allowed storage access manually and after that the file was copied to the new directory. Is there an universal way to allow permissions to storage in the app? I mean for versions 23 till 30

Comment: Starting in Android 11, apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage.So there is no more sense to backup database file locally if it can be stored only in app structure, as if the app is uninstalled, the backup is gone too

Comment: `in Android 11, apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage` Nonsense. First every app gets automatically an app specific directory on external storage. Have a look at getExternalFilesDir(). Second: every app can create directories in the usual public directories of external storage. All files there will not be removed at uninstall.

Comment: I just posted what I have found here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage. And yes, to access the directory that the system provides for your app, call getExternalFilesDirs(). And that is the app directory if I am not wrong. I want to store a backup OUTSIDE of app directory, somewhere in internal storage, which is not allowed anymore by Android 11, except media folders etc and it is suggested to use MediaStore API. But maybe I am wrong, but there is no step by step, how to backup a simple file to internal storage for Android 11 and then access it and restore.

Comment: I think, the best solution will be to store the file to Google drive via Rest API